# How to create a plugin which will update a field in a section when an entry is saved

Tags: plugin-development, field, sections

I am looking to create a plugin which will update a field in a section when I save an entry.

I will be getting the length of an MP3 file (using FFMPEG) I upload via assets and output the time to another input.

I can listen out for the `onSaveEntry` event, but I am unfamiliar with getting and putting data in a craft plugin.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question... have you had a go through the plugin docs? http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction I feel like between that and existing questions/answers here on Stack Exchange you'll find all the answers to get you there.

Comment: Thanks Brad. If there is a plugin which does something similar I can work with that. All I need to know is how to get the field data from a section when I save an entry and then add that data to a field before the save. I will take a look at and see if I can find the answer. I did take a look before